# The number of ways in which 10 identical apples can be distributed to six children so that each child receives at least one apple

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> The number of ways in which 10 identical apples can be distributed among 6 children so that each child receives at least one apple is?

My Attempt:

I got the number possibilities to be:
$(1,1,1,1,1,5), (1,1,1,1,2,4), (1,1,2,2,2,2), (1,1,1,2,2,3)$

Since they are identical apples, the number of ways each of these possibilities can be formed is 1.

However, I don't know how am I going to use this to solve the problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can first give everyone an apple. Then the question becomes: "What is the number of ways you can distribute 4 apples among 6 children?" - and for this you can use the "stars and bars" method.

Comment: @MattiP. The stars and bars method can be used right away. See theorem 1 here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: You overlooked $(1,1,1,1,3,3)$.

Comment: @BarryCipra  Ahhh! Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better approach.  Let $x_k$ be the number of apples received by the $k$th child.  Then 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 10$$
is an equation in the positive integers.  A particular solution corresponds to the placement of five addition signs in the nine spaces between successive ones in a row of ten ones. 
$$1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1$$
For instance, 
$$1 1 + 1 + 1 1 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 1$$ 
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 2$, $x_2 = 1$, $x_3 = 3$, $x_4 = x_5 = 1$, $x_6 = 2$.  The number of such solutions is the number of ways we can select five of the nine spaces in which to place an addition sign, which is
$$\binom{9}{5}$$

**Addendum:** Using Barry Cipra's observation, we can confirm this result by using your method.

*One child receives five apples and the other five children each receive one apple*: There are $6$ ways to select the child who receives five apples.

*One child receives four apples, another child receives two apples, and each of the other four children each receive one apple*:  There are six ways to choose the child who receives four apples and five ways to choose the child who receives two apples.  Hence, there are $6 \cdot 5 = 30$ such distributions.

*Two children each receive three apples and the other four children each receive one apple*:  There are $$\binom{6}{2} = 15$$ ways to select the two children who each receive two apples.

*One child receives three apples, two children each receive two apples, and the other three children each receive one apple*:  There are six ways to choose the child who receives three apples and $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to choose which two of the other five children each receive two apples.  Hence, there are $$\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{2} = 6 \cdot 10 = 60$$ such distributions.

*Four children each receive two apples and the other two children receive one apple*:  There are 
$$\binom{6}{4} = 15$$
ways to select which two children will receive two apples.

Observe that 
$$6 + 30 + 15 + 60 + 15 = \binom{9}{5}$$

Comment: Yes, I know this method and even got the answer from it. But can you please help me, how do I proceed with the given condition in the question?

Comment: And strangely, the answer given in my book is $3*\binom{9}{5}$

Comment: The answer in the book is wrong.  I did use the given condition.  If there were no such restriction, we would have to solve the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 10 \tag{1}$$ in the nonnegative integers.

Comment: A particular solution of equation 1 in the nonnegative integers corresponds to the placement of five addition signs in a row of $10$ ones.  For instance, $$1 1 + + 1 1 1 + 1 1 + 1 + 1 1$$ corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 2$, $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 3$, $x_4 = 2$, $x_5 = 1$, $x_6 = 2$.  The number of such solutions is $$\binom{10 + 5}{5} = \binom{15}{5}$$ since we must select which $5$ of the $15$ positions required for $10$ ones and $5$ addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

Comment: I have edited your answer to compare your approach with mine.