# Number of ways 6 things can be selected from a group of identical things

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> In how many ways can a party of 6 men be selected out of 10 Hindus, 8 Muslims, and 6 Christians if the party consists of at least one person of each religion( Consider only the religion of the person?

Now, I know this problem can be solved by finding the non-negative integral solution to the given equation,

$$x+y+z=6$$
Which the answer turns out to be $\binom{6-1}{3-1}$

But I want to know is there any other method of solving this problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can apply the method I used in the addendum to my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2687609/the-number-of-ways-in-which-10-identical-apples-can-be-distributed-to-six-childr) you posed.  This is not a permutation problem since we are not arranging objects, just selecting them.  The general class of problems you are solving fall under the topic combinatorics.

Comment: No of possibilities I could find is $(1,1,4), (1,2,3), (2,2,2)$ with the pattern following (Hindu, Muslim, Christian). However, that only gives me 3 solutions. But the answer is $\binom{5}{2}=10$ solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to permute them... That gives me 10.

Comment: Since you figured it out, I suggest you write an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

No.of possibilities according to the given condition is as follows,
$$(1,1,4), (1,2,3), (2,2,2)$$

Now we find the no.of ways we can select the persons of different religion corresponding to the possibilities.

1) For $(1,1,4)$,

No.of ways of selecting the persons = $3!$.

But since there are 2 1's, each selection will have two copies.

And since we only need to consider their religion (that means persons in a particular religion are identical), we need to divide the result by 2. That gives us,

$\frac{3!}{2} = 3$ ways

For $(1,2,3)$

No.of ways of selecting the persons = $3!$.

(Notice there aren't any repeating numbers in this case!)

2) For $(2,2,2)$

No.of ways of selecting the persons = $3!$.

Now, there are 3 repeating numbers.

That means there are $3!$ copies for each selection. Applying the same logic, we divide the result by $3!$.

$\frac{3!}{3!} = 1$

Adding all the result gives us,

$3+3!+1 = 10$

Answer (score 1):

**Stars and Bars**

Once we pre-select one of each religion, this is the same as asking "how many ways we can choose $3$ men from $9$ Hindus, $7$ Muslims, and $5$ Christians?" This is the same as asking how many ways to solve
$$
x+y+z=3
$$
with $x,y,z\ge0$. [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) say $\binom{5}{2}=10$.

---

**Generating Functions**

$$
\begin{align}
&\left[x^n\right]
\overbrace{\left(x+\cdots+x^{10}\right)}^{1\dots10\text{ Hindus}}
\overbrace{\left(x+\cdots+x^8\right)}^{1\dots8\text{ Muslims}}
\overbrace{\left(x+\cdots+x^6\right)}^{1\dots6\text{ Christians}}\\
&=\left[x^n\right]x^3\frac{1-x^{10}}{1-x}\frac{1-x^8}{1-x}\frac{1-x^6}{1-x}\\
&=\left[x^{n-3}\right]\frac{1-x^6-x^8-x^{10}+x^{14}+x^{16}+x^{18}-x^{24}}{(1-x)^3}\\
&=\left(\left[x^{n-3}\right]-\left[x^{n-9}\right]-\left[x^{n-11}\right]-\left[x^{n-13}\right]+\left[x^{n-17}\right]+\left[x^{n-19}\right]+\left[x^{n-21}\right]-\left[x^{n-27}\right]\right)\frac1{(1-x)^3}\\
&=\textstyle(-1)^{n-3}\left[\binom{-3}{n-3}-\binom{-3}{n-9}-\binom{-3}{n-11}-\binom{-3}{n-13}+\binom{-3}{n-17}+\binom{-3}{n-19}+\binom{-3}{n-21}-\binom{-3}{n-27}\right]\\[6pt]
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\textstyle\binom{n-1}{n-3}-\binom{n-7}{n-9}-\binom{n-9}{n-11}-\binom{n-11}{n-13}+\binom{n-15}{n-17}+\binom{n-17}{n-19}+\binom{n-19}{n-21}-\binom{n-25}{n-27}}
\end{align}
$$
This is the number of ways to pick a group of $n$ people from a pool of $10$ Hindus, $8$ Muslims, and $6$ Christians, where there is at least $1$ of each.

The only one of these that is not $0$ for $n=6$ is $\binom{n-1}{n-3}=\binom{5}{3}$.

Note that we could reduce the last line to
$$
\textstyle\binom{n-1}{2}-\binom{n-7}{2}-\binom{n-9}{2}-\binom{n-11}{2}+\binom{n-15}{2}+\binom{n-17}{2}+\binom{n-19}{2}-\binom{n-25}{2}
$$
except that the equation $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$ only holds when $k$ and $n-k$ are non-negative integers.

Comment: This is the number of *positive* integer solutions to $x+y+z=6$. This is different than the number of non-negative integral solutions to $x+y+z=6$, which is $\binom{8}{2}=28$. Perhaps this is what you meant when you said you wanted methods other than counting the number of *non-negative* integral solutions to $x+y+z=6$.

Answer (score -1):

The number of ways arranging this would be 10 .

And the possibilities are :

( 1 , 1 , 4)
( 1 , 2 , 3)
( 1 , 3 , 2)
( 2 , 2 , 2)
( 2 , 3 , 1)
( 2 , 1 , 3)
( 3 , 2 , 1)
( 3 , 1 , 2)
( 4 , 1 , 1)
( 1, 4 , 1)

following the pattern ( Hindu, Muslim , Christian )

Comment: The question seems to be asking about other *methods* for solving the problem.  What is your *method* here?  To simply list them all out and hope that you don't miss any?  I don't see how this answers the question...